# WebRTC getUserMedia promise api support in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia

Does chrome support promise based APIs for WebRTC? I am not able to get the getUserMedia() promised based API working in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Mitel WebRTC client </title>
        <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
        <script src='dist/webrtc.min.js'></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function startUp() {

                var options = {
                    audio: true,
                    video: true
                };
                if (getUserMedia) {
                    getUserMedia(options)
                    .then(function (stream) {
                        console.log("Acquired audio and video!");
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("WebRTC not supported on this browser");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="startUp();">
        <h1>WebRTC Promise API Client Application</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the console, I see the following error

```
This appears to be Chrome
adapter-latest.js:32 chrome: {"audio":true,"video":true}
adapter-latest.js:410 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'webkitGetUserMedia' on 'Navigator': The callback provided as parameter 2 is not a function.
```

I want to make use of promise based API. Am I missing something?

Comment: I get the same error on Firefox as well, when above code is served (using adapter shim). Firefox says it supports promise based API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Comment: "[Deprecated
This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia)".

Comment: @Kevin I am making use of the shim/adaptor. And I think it makes use of Navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia

Comment: @Kevin - you were pointing to the correct issue. If instead of using getUserMedia(), I use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() then the promise based API works. I was assuming that the adaptor/shim layer will handle such issues and would alias to the proper API (in this case navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()). Can you put that as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the problem is in your case, so I can't formulate a proper answer that will benefit future users. But you can answer your own question and accept it, you can explain exactly what you did to make it work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not implemented yet in Chrome, but it works there if you use the official [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/) WebRTC polyfill: https://jsfiddle.net/srn9db4h/

```
var constraints = { video: true, audio: true };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(stream => video.srcObject = stream)
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Firefox and Edge support it natively FWIW.

**Update:** Chrome (50) appears to support this now. And Chrome 52 even supports `srcObject`.

Comment: As @kevin also mentioned earlier, the proper way is to use the namespaced api which is 
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(). I was under the wrong impression that adapter.js will automatically translate the getUserMedia() call to navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() if the underlying browser supports the newer namespaced API.

Comment: @sthustfo right, that would have been clever, but as I understand adapter.js is trying to move away from non-standard helper functions, to purely polyfilling the spec.

Comment: But it doesn't support on Safari!

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle It [works](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jib1/srn9db4h/show/) in [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/).

Comment: @jib Yes right as you said it works on Safari Technology Preview. But is there any way to work this on basic Safari!

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not recommended but still you can try this to test your project by disabling security for media.

```
chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure
```

you can add your IP and chrome will treat it as secure.

Comment: Where to add this in chrome?

Comment: Type this in the address bar like a url.This will directly take you there.

Answer (score 1):

To access navigator.mediaDevices you must to connect your site with HTTPS connection. There are no access this feature with HTTP.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images/

> Warning: Direct access to the camera is a powerful feature. It requires consent from the user, and your site MUST be on a secure origin (HTTPS).

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error if you're running Chrome your app in http. If so, you should run your app as https. Only localhost urls with http are supported by Chrome.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/jib1/srn9db4h/ `
// not working

`https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/srn9db4h/`
//working with https
```