# Docker - Can't get user webcam: getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins

Tags: python, docker, flask, webcam, tracking.js

**WHAT WORKS**

I created a simple Web Application in *Flask* that takes care of operating a simple `return render_template("index.html")` when the root node is accessed by a Web Browser.

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def show_index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=80)
```

The index.html is a simple page that uses *tracking.js* in order to get the user webcam and track his/her face in the live video stream.

Opening cmd and typing `python app.py` results in `Running on http://127.0.0.1:80/`

Accessing the above mentioned URL results in the correct display of the page, that asks me for permission to use the camera, opens it and correctly tracks my face in the live video feed. So it's all working fine till here.

**WHAT DOES NOT WORKS**

The problem I'm experiencing arises when I dockerize my application using **Docker**. `docker-machine ip` is 192.168.99.100

Opening cmd and typing: `docker run -p 4000:80 my_face_track_app` results in: `Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/`

Accessing 192.168.99.100:4000 results in the correct display of `index.html` but I am not asked anymore for permission on the camera and inspecting the JS console I read the following exception:

```
getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins
```

Here the full error log:

[image]

I know the error is telling me I'm not serving the page in HTTPS.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?
What would be the proper solution to the issue or a possible walkaround? 
Any help will be highly appreciated, thank you a lot in advance

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED TO DO IN ORDER TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM**

Since an HTTPS serving of the page is needed in order for JS to execute the function `getUserMedia()` I tought about serving my Flask application with an SSL certificate by modifying app.py like this:

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import OpenSSL

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def show_index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=80, ssl_context="adhoc")
```

I then dockerized the app building a new image. Typing:

```
docker run -p 443:80 facetrackapphttps
```

Results in

```
 Running on https://127.0.0.1:80
```

So yeah, here HTTPS is ON: the problem is that the port 80 of the HTTPS Flask App is mapped to the port 443 of the `docker-machine ip` 192.168.99.100.

Trying to access 192.168.99.100:443 does not work and nothing is shown.

Does anybody have an idea about how to do this?

Comment: I think [this might  be the cause of your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34237216/147356). That also suggests that if you continue to access your exposed port via `localhost` that things will Just Work.

Comment: I already read that. I already tried that but I'm not having any luck in getting this to work

Comment: So, after reading that, what have you tried? The solution appears to be either (a) use https, or (b) access your service over the localhost interface.  Your question doesn't show that you tried either of those things.

Comment: I enabled HTTPS protocol by typing: app.run(port=80, ssl_context="adhoc"). Then I dockerized the app and did docker run -p 443:80 facetrackapphttps. This results in Running on https://127.0.0.1:80 so yeah HTTPS is on. But the problem is that the 80 port of the HTTPS Flask App is mapped to the 443 port of docker-machine ip 192.168.99.100. Trying to access 192.168.99.100:443 does not work and nothing is shown. Do you know how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is bound to `127.0.0.1` inside the container, you're not going to be able to access it from your host. According to the [flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.run), flask will bind to 127.0.0.1 by default.

You'll need to modify your service so that it binds to `0.0.0.0` inside the container:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, ssl_context="adhoc")
```

Comment: Yeah, I made it work myself doing `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=443, ssl_context="adhoc")`. I exposed the 443 port in the Docker file. I then typed in cmd : `docker run -p 443:443 facetrackapphttps` and it worked smoothly. Thank you a lot anyway. The  `host='0.0.0.0' ` does the trick.