# MediaDevices: devicechange event not working on ubuntu server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, mediadevices

I am using `MediaDevices: devicechange event` in my react application. On local machin all working good but when i deployed application on server (ubuntu) it gives me the following error
[image]

The only difference is OS on local machine I use windows but server is ubuntu.
Here is my function

```
export function useDevices() {
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState<MediaDeviceInfo[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDevices = () => navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => setDevices(devices));
    navigator.mediaDevices.addEventListener('devicechange', getDevices);
    getDevices();

    return () => {
      navigator.mediaDevices.removeEventListener('devicechange', getDevices);
    };
  }, []);

  return devices;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165614/navigator-mediadevices-getusermedia-is-not-working-and-neither-does-webkitgetuse) getUserMedia() is no longer supported in chrome browser over http:// (Unsecure Origin) , It will work on https:// (Secure Origin)

For testing purposes, You can run chrome with the --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as- for this, you need to visit this link in chrome `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` and enable the option, add your site URL in the text area, and relaunch the browser. Now you should able to use getmediadevices method.